# How to use devmem command in debian 11?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer

Why Debian doesn't have `devmem2`

I tried to install devmem using command `sudo apt-get install devmem2`

I got the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package devmem2
```

Before the above command, i tried `sudo apt-get update`

for which I got the output

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian bullseye InRelease  
Reading package lists... Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devmem2` isn’t packaged in Debian, presumably because no one has seen sufficient need for a package.

It isn’t too hard to build:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radii/devmem2/master/devmem2.c
make devmem2
```

That will leave a `devmem2` binary you can use.

If you really want a package you can rebuild the Ubuntu package:

```
sudo apt install devscripts debhelper build-essential
dget -ux https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/devmem2/0.0-0ubuntu2/devmem2_0.0-0ubuntu2.dsc
cd devmem2-0.0
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
cd -
sudo dpkg -i devmem2_0.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```